# Visual Studio 2017 failed to install several components

Tags: visual-studio-2017

The installer for release version of Visual Studio 2017 Community edition failed for several components

> The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due
>   to one or more package failures.
>
> Incomplete workloads
>       Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26228.0)
>
> Incomplete components
>       Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2,version=15.0.26208.0)
>
> You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your
>   selections for the above workloads and components and retry the
>   installation, or remove the product from your machine.
>
> Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to
>   the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing
>   reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from
>   each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been
>   reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue
>   has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people
>   will be able to find solutions or workarounds.
>
> Package 'AndroidEmulator_API23V2,version=1.0.23' failed to download
>   from 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=841569'.
>       Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=AndroidEmulator_API23V2;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80072f7d
>       Impacted workloads
>           Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.26228.0)
>       Impacted components
>           Google Android Emulator (API Level 23) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2,version=15.0.26208.0)
>       Details
>           WebClient download failed: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.
>           Bits download failed: Error context: BG_ERROR_CONTEXT_REMOTE_FILE, Error code: -2147012739
>           WinInet download failed: Function: InternetReadFile, HR: -2147012739, Message: Unknown error 12157

Does this Mobile development with .NET  impact in anyway Windows UWP development?  I don't really need the Android development tools at this moment.

What is the best course of action for this - I tried the install twice, with the same result - can I install the components later on their own?

**EDIT**: Visual Studio seems to run correctly, and I can open my UWP project and run it so everything seems to work ok so far.  This is the version of the application that was installed

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
Version 15.0.26228.9 D15RTWSVC
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586
Installed Version: Community
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you have this file on your machine:

```
%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe
```

If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a `-full` param:

```
InstallCleanup.exe -full
```

If not, please manually delete the folder:

```
%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
```

Relaunch the newly downloaded `vs_enterprise.exe` (or `vs_professional.exe` or `vs_community.exe`). Allow the first step to install the installer.

Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (`.NET` desktop and the like), close it. Go launch the same `InstallCleanup.exe` to clean up old build of VS.

Then relaunch `vs_enterprise.exe` and install

Comment: After following those steps the installer warns 'Visual Studio cannot be installed to a nonempty directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community'' - This mean I have to go to Programs and Features and uninstall VS2017 first right?  After that do I just delete the contents of the folder?

Comment: After doing the above and reinstall latest installer it worked with no more errors. Thanks.

Comment: This removes the whole Visual studio installation, that's not really a fix.