# Visual Studio 2017 failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio Professional 2017 in Windows 10. Whenever I try to install the ASP.NET and Web Development package, I get an error with the included log. I have tried the steps outlined in this solution: [Visual Studio 2017 failed to install several components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847713/visual-studio-2017-failed-to-install-several-components). I also followed the link in the log file and followed the instructions found here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24352/vs2017-installer-fails-trying-to-update-package-mi.html however I received the same error. Visual Studio still opens and works fine (as far as I can tell), however I'm missing a lot of components that I need.

Many thanks in advance!

Error log:

```
    The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)

Incomplete components
    ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature,version=15.0.26208.0' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2146498548
    Impacted workloads
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26412.1)
    Impacted components
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170608105455_234_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log
    Details
        Command executed: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\dism.exe" /online /quiet /norestart /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"netfx4extended-aspnet45" /All /logPath:"C:\Users\Oliver\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170608105455_234_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log"
        Return code: -2146498548
        Return code details: The Windows feature is unknown.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to download full offline installer - there is about 30Gb

vs_Community.exe --layout HERE_PATH_TO_SAVE --lang en-US